# Linux sed command

Tags: sed

Can anyone help me understand what the following command does in Linux.

```
sed -i file.c -e "s/  __attribute__ ((__unused__))$$/# ifndef __cplusplus\n  __attribute__ ((__unused__));\n# endif/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing an inplace search-and-replace on `file.c`, looking for

```
 __attribute__ (__unused__)
```

at the end of a line, and replacing any occurences with

```
# ifndef __cplusplus\n  __attribute__ (__unused__);\nendif
```

which works out to:

```
# ifndef __cplusplus
    __attribute__ (__unused__)
# endif
```

THe doubled brackets and $ signs are to "escape" those characters in the shell.

Comment: I think you'll find that the double bracket syntax is part of the `__attribute__` specifier in gcc. And I'm not certain about the `$$` escaping anything, since `$$` is a shell variable that returns the current pid.

Comment: True, but the $$ is within a double-quoted string, so it's going to be expanded.

Comment: Please correct your answer. The doubled characters do not do any "escaping".

Answer (score 1):

It adds `# ifndef __cplusplus` and `# endif` around `__attribute__ ((__unused__));` in file.c

Answer (score 1):

As Greg says in a comment, the `$$` will expand to the PID of the shell which doesn't make sense in the context. If it was a single dollar sign, or wasn't there, the command could be shortened to:

```
sed -i file.c -e "s/  __attribute__ ((__unused__))$/# ifndef __cplusplus\n&;\n# endif/"
```

since `&` brings forward what was matched between the first pair of delimiters (slashes in this example). The single dollar sign causes the match to only be made if the string is at the end of the line.